# Testing SOAP web service on java

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap, wsdl

I'm going to test a generic soap web service on java. My inputs are wsdl(file or url), request xml and expected response xml. I'm going to send the request xml to the web service and compare the response of the web service to the expected response xml.

How am I suppose to do this?
Is there an open source API that I can use?

Comment: Are you using a framework to do it ? AXIS or CXF or are you doing a plain post of SOAP on HTTP ?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Can you please elaborate your question having your effort like code or something so that people could get your problem early and help you? Thanks!

Comment: Use SOAP UI (https://www.soapui.org/)

Comment: Im trying to use the soap ui api. but Im currently having issues with the pom.xml. the maven can'tdownload the dependency of soap ui. do you have any references for this soap ui? thanks

Comment: As of now Im just searching for other tools that I can use for my implementation. do you have any recommentation @RamachandranGA? thanks

Comment: Although i am redirecting you to a different article and different library , i really loved the approach that is provided here (https://camel.apache.org/tutorial-example-reportincident-part1.html) . Specifically look for unit testing your web service. The author uses CXF  , you can use a potion of your liking, You can also use SOAP UI as a postrer mentioned as a standalone testing tool!

Comment: I will try this one. and I'll give a feedback regarding this. Im using websphere as my server and eclipse ide by the way. thanks!

Comment: You can also look at SOAP UI docs  https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html#1-basic-configuration